# Can I consume a Nuget package within a Node project?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2017, nuget, azure-artifacts

I am working with Visual Studio 2017. I started from; Basic Node.js Express 4 Application.

I have a private Nuget in VSTS which has a .Net tool I would now like to use in the Node.js project (to perform some domain specific build-like tasks).

Is it possible to add a Nuget reference into a Node.js project (just to download the tool)?

*I've seen that VSTS provides npm, but this would seem to be incompatible with my existing Nuget packages.*

Comment: Hi James, Did you find a way to achieve this? if yes can you share the details?

Comment: James any solution or workaround you found?

Comment: @AdnanAli, no, but coming back to this (4 years!) later in retrospect, you could probably execute the Nuget CLI via Node.js. For example, use JavaScript to run PowerShell which gets and runs nuget.exe, as a Node.js build task. Not actually done this myself but possible in theory (I think!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a Nuget reference into a Node.js project (just to download the tool)?

I am afraid you can not do that at this moment.

Because Nuget does not currently support the `node.js` project even if you just download the tool. When you use nuget on the `node.js` project, we always get the error 'Project "Default" is not found.'. `npm` is the right solution for package management for `node.js` project.

See similar issues on GitHub for some more details:

[Cannot install packages in Node.js project - Project "Default" is not found](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2145)

[Nuget package manager cannot 'see' Node.JS projects](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/326)

Hope this helps.